# Do I need to repeat the word "to" when there's a comma?

Tags: prepositions, commas

Please excuse my ignorance. I don't enough of the verbiage to properly phrase the question in the title.

Example:

"Karen tried numerous times to tell her daughter to be herself, and (to) not change just to please others."

I think of it like like this:

"Karen tried to tell her daughter to: (1) Be herself; (2) not change just to please others."

Thinking of it in this way, the word "to" shouldn't need to be duplicated because the original to works both ways.

What is the rule here?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a style issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's optional, but you need to be consistent across the series.  This is especially important when there are three items.  However if one of the items in the series doesn't use "to" and another does, usage wouldn't be optional.  Consider:

```
Karen told her daughter to smile, to relax, and that she loved her.
```

In this case, you couldn't leave off "to" in "to relax" since it doesn't apply to the final part of the series "and that she loved her".

However either of the following would be fine:

```
Karen told her daughter to smile, to relax, and to have fun.
Karen told her daughter to smile, relax, and have fun.
```

The same rule applies to other prepositions and articles.  Repeated use is optional unless some items in the series do not permit them.